# How to unit test nested functions in angular using jasmine-karna

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am trying to test SetRole function which is calling GetRole function in the end, but I am unable to cover the line in code coverage. Please guide me related to testing cascaded function, nested function, function in the function.

> ***component.ts***

```
SetRole(inp){
this.role = inp;
this.GetRole()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    it('SetRole',() => {
    
    const inp = 'dummyInput';
    const spy = spyOn(component,'GetRole')
    component.SetRole(inp)
    
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```